# $C^{*} $ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

‎I have recently started reading the subject of $C^{*} $ - Algebra, ‎But I have several questions in this field.

‎let $A$ be a $C^{*} $ - algebra and $a‎ , ‎b \in A $ are hermitian‎  ,  ‎$ ab =  ba $‎.

**I would like to know ‎if:**‎

1:‎  $ f‎ : ‎\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, and ‎$ a \leq b $‎ ‎,  ‎then $ f ( a ) \leq f ( b )$.

2‎:‎ ‎$ f‎ : ‎‎‎‎\mathbb{R}‎ \longrightarrow  ‎‎‎\mathbb{R}‎‎$ ‎is a‎ ‎real ‎function ,‎ ‎then‎ ‎$  a f( b) =  b‎ ‎f( a‎ ‎)‎ $‎

**thank you.**

Answer (score 1):

These aren't even true in the case $A = \mathbb{C}$.

For 1.) just consider $f(x) = -x$.

For 2.) let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$ with $f(x)$ such that $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)\neq 0$.

Comment: do you mean the both of 1 and 2  are false ?

Comment: Yes they are both false even in the case A = $\mathbb{C}$